# How to make a common login page for two different react apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two different react-apps made by create-react-app running on the same server but different ports. I wish to have a common login and authentication page for both the apps and need suggestions for the same. Basically, I just need to pass on the login information to both the apps from the login page.

Comment: Different port means different origins, so you cannot share login cookies. You would need oAuth for that. I suggest using an Reverse Proxy to host both apps on the same origin.

Comment: Please specify what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a `Single Sign On(SSO)`. May be this article will help you.

[SSO Using react](https://codeburst.io/building-a-simple-single-sign-on-sso-server-and-solution-from-scratch-in-node-js-ea6ee5fdf340)

Answer (score 0):

You can build server for authentication after you check token with well-know...!

Well-know are any path allow user connect

If you login at FirstApp after connect SecondApp was not login. You can callback access-token on url

The grand type above : explicit..!

you can read: [Explicit authen](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/04/01/implicit-vs-explicit-authentication-in-browser-based-applications/)